# EJB3 is null and triggers a NullPointerException when using it in a j2se environment

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I've got a `NullPointerException` using EJB3 in a J2SE environment (without EJB3 container)

Briefly, I've got a stateless bean implementing an interface.
When I call it in another class like in a main, a `NullPointerException` is triggered.

Sample:

```
@stateless
@Local(IMyInterface.class)
public class myBean implements IMyInterface{...}

public class Main{
   @EJB
   IMyInterface myInterface;

   public static void main(String[] args){
      Result result = myInterface.myBeanMethod(); // Exception happens here
   }
}
```

I guess I miss some initialization stuff because the EJB is null when I first try to use it...

Thanks for your help,

Comment: @stateless shouldn't be all lower-case. And - EJB 3.0 or EJB 3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you **can** use JPA (which is part of EJB 3) "Entity Beans" (actually, POJOs) in a J2SE environment, you **can't** use Session Beans  without a container and  you **can't** benefit from injection of resources using the `@Resource` or the more specialized `@EJB` and `@WebServiceRef` annotations in a non-managed environment, i.e. a container. In other words, only managed components support injection (Servlets, JSF Managed beans, EJB components, etc).

So, in your case, you'll need to:

1. Deploy your Session Bean in a Java EE container (like JBoss, GlassFish, WebLogic, etc)
2. Lookup the remote EJB using explicitly its global JNDI name. The code will look like that:

   ```
   Foo foo = (Foo) new InitialContext().lookup("FooEJB");
   ```

A few additional remarks:

- With EJB 3.0, the global `JNDI` name is container dependent so I can't tell you what it will be exactly (EJB 3.1 finally introduced "[portable global `JNDI` names](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#What_is_the_syntax_for_portable_global_)").
- You'll need to set up the JNDI environment (which is container dependent) for the lookup either by providing a `jndi.properties` on the class path or by using the [`InitialContext(Hashtable)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html#InitialContext%28java.util.Hashtable%29) constructor.
- You'll need to provide the application server "client library" on the class path of the client (which is obviously specific to each product).

Search for previous questions or open a new one if you need more specific guidance.

Answer (score 3):

EJBs can't work without a container. The dependencies (`@EJB`) are injected if the beans are instantiated by the container. If *you* are the one instantiating them, it is your responsibility to set the dependencies.

Furthermore, you are trying to use a *non-static* variable from a a *static* method - this won't even compile.